# User space APC queue length in Windows

Tags: c, windows, multithreading, winapi, apc

What is maximum length of user space APC queue to one thread in Windows? I read Windows Internals 6 Part 1 and didn't finded any information about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no fixed limit. KAPC structures are allocated from [nonpaged pool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa965226.aspx) and linked to a thread by a single [LIST_ENTRY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff554296.aspx) structure. Nonpaged pool is [limited by available system resources only](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/markrussinovich/2009/03/10/pushing-the-limits-of-windows-paged-and-nonpaged-pool/).